# fail to crawl a dynamic loading web page using scrapy-splash

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, scrapy-splash

Greetings. I am new to scrapy-splash.
i try to extract car information from following webpage by using scrapy-splash
https://www.lexusserramonte.com/new-inventory/index.htm
i tried a lot, just does not work. Make no difference compared to just using scrapy without splash plugin.

Just wondering anyone can extract information from that URL? if you can, please share your code.
much much appreciate

Comment: What have you tried so far, can you please show us your effort ?

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use splash for this task.. all you need is to reverse engineer API calls.

All the needed info on cars can be found by this link https://www.lexusserramonte.com/apis/widget/INVENTORY_LISTING_DEFAULT_AUTO_NEW:inventory-data-bus1/getInventory?compositeType=new

Comment: thanks!! it's very good option!!! how did u find it? from page source or inspect request?
i would like to learn more because i need pagination as well

Comment: use "network" tab of inspect tools to check which xhr requests are performed during site navigation.